# how to create an app with in app inside a Django project? How that app can be registered to setting py file?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

*project- New.app-app
want to add an app inside app

1.how to register this to the setting.py file?

2. what are the things I should be worried once I have an app with in an app?

Comment: better if you prefer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial01/  Documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create inner app using command

```
django-admin startapp demoapp
```

Here i created Two apps first at Project Directory & second one is
in app directory

```
├───demo
│   └───__pycache__
├───myapp  <-------- this is primary app
│   ├───demoapp <-------- this inner app
│   │   ├───migrations
│   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   ├───templates
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───migrations
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───templates
│   └───__pycache__
└───static
```

Now do settings in settins.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp', <-------- this is primary app
    'myapp.demoapp', <-------- this inner app
]
```

Now do settings in (demoapp > apps.py)

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class DemoappConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'myapp.demoapp'
```

Comment: So when we add template folder to the inner app ,how should be the path ??
templates / my_app / inner_app is this how the directory should be?

Comment: Put templates folder in app
No need to set path for templates

Answer (score 0):

To create an app in Django do this:

**First**, navigate to project folder in terminal or cmd and run above command:

```
python manage.py startapp appname #This will create an app inside Django project
```

**Second**, after create app:

In settings.py file:

add your app in INSTALLED_APP:
ex:

```
INSTALLED_APPs = [
   'appname',
]
```

This is the only thing you have to do after create app.

Comment: can we create another app inside the app that we just created  ?

Comment: why you want to create an app inside an app? app means nothing but it's just a sections of our project

Comment: Yes sir , I understood that they are sections of our projects. Now that  I have a project idea which I have divided into six apps .  Out of the those six  app, one of the app is just a sub-app of another . That made me think of adding the app with in the app so that  it will be more organized if it is possible . And really like to learn new things while doing a project so that I could learn.

Comment: share that structure here, i want to see